# $T(n) = nT(n/2) ,T(1)=1$ How can I solve this with backward subsitituon?

Tags: recurrence-relations, substitution

$n$ can be power of 2 or we can assume $Integerpart(n/2)$ ==> int casting.

I find the recurrence relation of function but How can I solve this with using backward subsitituon ?

[My recurrence relation solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILc8d.png)

Comment: You can still use your trick, just observe that $S(k) = 2^k S(k-1)$ and we know the value for $S(0)$, so you could use backward substitution to unroll $S(k)$ until you get to $S(0)$ on the RHS. Using your "unrolled" expression for $S(k)$ you should be able to find $T(n)$.

Comment: Thank you I use and find solution. @rarwoan

Comment: If you solved the problem using my hint, then I'll post it as an answer to close the question (you can accept it if you find it useful).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out in my comment, you can use the next hint:

Observe that $S(k) = 2^k S(k-1)$ and the fact that we know the value of $S(0)$. Next use backward substitution to "unroll" $S(k)$ until you get to $S(0)$ on the RHS. Using your "unrolled" expression for $S(k)$ you should be able to find $T(n)$

:)

Answer (score 1):

$$
T\left(2^{\log_2 n}\right) = n T\left(2^{\log_2 \frac n2}\right)
$$

now calling

$$
\cases{
\mathcal{T}\left(\cdot\right) = T\left(2^{(\cdot)}\right)\\
z = \log_2 n
}
$$

we have the equivalent recurrence

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right)=2^z \mathcal{T}\left(z-1\right)
$$

This recurrence has as solution

$$
\mathcal{T}\left(z\right) = c_0 2^z\cdot 2^{z-1}\cdot 2^{z-2}\cdots 1 = c_0 2^{\frac{z(z+1)}{2}}
$$

now with the backwards substitution $z = \log_2 n$ we recover

$$
T(n) = c_02^{\frac{(\log_2 n)^2+\log_2 n}{2}} = c_02^{\frac{(\log_2 n)^2}{2}}\sqrt{n}
$$

and due to the initial condition

$$
T(n) = 2^{\frac{(\log_2 n)^2}{2}}\sqrt{n}=n^{\frac{1+\log_2 n}{2}}
$$

Comment: I would like to mark the solution as an answer, but after the answer of rarwoan, I came to the conclusion that way. Thanks anyway :) @Cesareo

Answer (score 0):

Notice that the expression $T(n)$ starts with $n$ so in general you have

$$T(n)=n\frac{n}{2}\frac{n}{4}...\frac{n}{2^k}...1$$

Obviously the last $1$ is in the same format so it must be

$$\frac{n}{2^M}=1$$

or

$$n=2^M$$

From there it is obvious that we have $M+1$ terms in form of

$$\frac{n}{2^k}=1$$

where $M$ is $\log_2(n)$

We can write then

$$T(n)=\frac{n^{M+1}}{ 2^{ \frac{M(M+1)} {2} } }$$

or precisely after the substitution of $M$

$$T(n)=n^{\log_4(2n)}$$

Comment: Very sorry because I edited your answer instead of mine. I left it as it was. No modification.

Comment: According to your solution  if n=4 $T(4) = n^{log_4(4/2)} = 2$ but $T(4)$ must be $8$

Comment: @bluefox The steps are just fine it is a mix in the derivation of the last expression. Am I a student here now so I do not pass or something? Just joking. But yes this was meant to be a helpful hint. But the solution is now ok. The question was about backtracking and this is exactly how you do it.